# How to send request by refresh_token after getting 401 error ?

Tags: c#, typescript, oauth-2.0, jwt, owin

I'm trying to implement "Remember me" feature.

I'm trying to do it by using refresh_token.

In the begining, user gets refresh_token, access_token and its expire_time.

If access_token's expire_time end, I'm giving 401 error in http_service. However, I would like to refresh access_token in that case too.

**The problem is that :** Although the parameter "content" is filled, it cannot passed to APP-side. I mean "OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context" ' parameter' count is zero. This only happens after getting 401 error. I mean post request is not working properly when it get 401 error. I do not understand why content is not passed to APP side ? Can somebody help me ?

I used this code:

**UI**

```
if (error.status == 401) { //Unauthorized
            if (localStorage.getItem("refresh_token")) // Remember me için kontrol !
            {
                let content: any = {};
                let loginUrl: any = "vbsecure/token";
                content.refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
                content.grant_type = "refresh_token";
                content.rememberMe = localStorage.getItem("rememberme");

                console.log("content", content);

                this.post(loginUrl, content, ContentTypes.URLENCODED).subscribe(
                    tp => {
                        if (!!tp) {

                            sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', tp.access_token);
                            sessionStorage.setItem('token_type', tp.token_type);
                            localStorage.setItem('access_token', tp.access_token);
                            localStorage.setItem('token_type', tp.token_type);

                            console.log("TP", tp);

                            //this.loggedIn = true;
                            this.router.navigate(['']);
                        }
                    },
                    err => {
                        console.log("http.service 401 içindeki hata");
                        //this.ems.onShowDialog.next({ content: "Hatalı kullanıcı adı / şifre", title: "Hata" });
                        this.router.navigate(['login']);
                    });
            }
```

**APP**

```
  public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        var allowedOrigin = "*";
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Accept", new[] { "text/html", "application/xhtml+xml", "*/*" });

        if (context.Parameters.Get("rememberMe") != "undefined")
        {
            _rememberMe = Convert.ToBoolean(context.Parameters.Get("rememberMe"));
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("_rememberMe", _rememberMe);
        }
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```